# Do we have to include jar files in eclipse project if we are using maven?

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

I am new to maven. 
The POM file in maven contains all the dependencies that we need in our project.
So we don't have to externally add any JAR's to the buildpath in eclipse.Right?

Comment: Right : ) unless you want your build to be not portable and cause issues to other developers and to the future yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right. Maven will download dependencies and M2Eclipse (Eclipse plugin for integrating Eclipse with Maven) will setup a build path for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Two Solutions - 1 Using Eclipse IDE**

1. Install the Maven (M2E Eclipse Plugin) if you use older version of eclipse, If you [download](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Juno/SR2) the latest eclipse.
2. Point your settings.xml and create a maven project from your eclipse, it is better keep Group Id as com.yourcompany.app Artifact Id as yourProjectName and Version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT depends on your Architecture Standards set by your company. Also Packaging can be as WAR file for WebApplication, EAR file for Enterprise Application. You can find the numerous list of examples from Maven Site.

**2 From Command Line**

3. Install Maven from [Apache Maven site](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi), Would recommend to go for the latest version -apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip.
4. Set the Maven Home in the Environment Variables as shown in the below figure.
   [image: MavenPath]
5. Edit Your Path variable as %MAVEN_HOME%\bin, verify your installation by using this command from your command prompt. It should display the Maven Home and Java Version, which confirms your maven successful installation.
   [image: Maven Verification]
6. Paste your settings.xml (C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf) given by your build team or Architecture team for accessing your internal repository. And keep a **backup** of the original settings.xml (which is default download from Maven site)
7. Run these commands from your command prompt. 
   mvn eclipse:clean -e
   mvn eclipse:eclipse -e (which will **automatically** set your project build path as shown in the below figure)

[image: m2repo]

8. It will resolve your compilation issues and your project is ready as an deploy-able artifact